# namedtuple._source not working in python 3.7

Tags: python, collections, attributes, namedtuple

I've tried with this code

```
from collections import namedtuple
t = namedtuple('t', 'a b c')
i = t(1,2,3)
print(i._source, t._source)
```

But when I run it it says that there is no attribute `_source` (for `t` and therefore also for `i`). Has it been eliminated since 3.6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields), the attribute `_source` has been removed from `namedtuples` in Python 3.7.

> *Changed in version 3.7:* Remove the *verbose* parameter and the `_source` attribute.