# What is the substitute of _source attribute for namedtuple in python 3.8.5?

Tags: python-3.x, namedtuple

I am doing something like below :-

```
 from collections import namedtuple
 Stock=namedtuple('Stock', ''' symbol
                            year
                            month
                            day
                            open
                            high
                            low
                            close''')

nifty_tcs=Stock('TCS',2021,3,31,3010,3080,3000,3060)
print(Stock._fields)
# Above works fine and returns output ('symbol', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close')
print(Stock._source)
```

It causes the error :-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-c4df9719ea17> in <module>
---->  Stock._source

AttributeError: type object 'Stock' has no attribute '_source'
```

Has something changed between previous python version and python3.8.5 ?

Thanks

Comment: "[Changed in version 3.7: Removed the verbose parameter and the _source attribute.](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [namedtuple.\_source not working in python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358849/namedtuple-source-not-working-in-python-3-7)

Comment: You can [read the discussion thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue28638) around removing `_source`, which doesn't indicate anyone implementing a replacement afaict

Comment: Also, if you're on 3.7+, consider using the newer [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) instead of namedtuple

Comment: In general, stuff that begins with `_` should be considered private or implementation-specific. You should not use it precisely for the reason you are running into.